# page load on my Wordpress site not smooth with Chrome

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10.

I've built a simple site using Wordpress and the Manifest theme. My site is located here: http://www.andrewpickin.com, and the Manifest theme has its homepage here: http://jimbarraud.com/manifest/

If I browse the site in Firefox (in Ubuntu) then each page loads smoothly and fast. If I browse it in Chrome (in Ubuntu) then sometimes pages take a millisecond to load, which creates a feeling that the page is flashing or jerking on load.

It's not a major issue, but I feel it should be something that can be fixed. Does anyone have any ideas? Maybe I need to modify the Manifest theme...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this solved my issue: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/improve-my-load-times/